# Vertical alignment in Style

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a very simple style. The code behind does nothing (for now).

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xxx:Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type fluent:Button}">
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and then in the MainWindow I'll use it as:

```
<xxx:Button Content="1" FontSize="46" />
```

This causes the text to not be vertically centered. I asked a different question about this and the response was that its due to the way fonts scale and how they all scale differently. That's well and all, but how can I universally center the content in the border without knowing what it is? In the above example its just text, but it can be an icon or button, etc. Those all seem to center properly... is there a trick to getting it to work with text since every font will have a different "fudge factor"?

Comment: Any different results setting `VerticalContentAlignment="Center"` for your `ContentPresenter`?

Comment: @MikeGuthrie The ContentPresenter doesn't have that property.

Comment: Sorry, guess I was looking in the wrong context on [MS docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentpresenter.verticalcontentalignment).  Things get confusing when the same names are used across multiple assemblies and namespaces.